# Laravel Docker Call to undefined function MyActionFunction

Tags: php, laravel, docker

I'm new to docker and laravel.
I'm trying to dockerize a laravel application, the source code is not mine.
I used Sail for local tests, but now I want to build a production image. So I write a dockerfile with my deps:

```
FROM php:8.1.4-fpm-alpine3.15 as laravel-deps

RUN apk add --no-cache \
    freetype-dev \
    libpng-dev \
    libjpeg-turbo-dev \
    libtool \
    libwebp-dev \
    libzip-dev \
    mariadb-dev \
    pcre-dev ${PHPIZE_DEPS} \
    zip \
    && pecl install redis \
    && docker-php-ext-configure gd --with-freetype  \
    && docker-php-ext-install \
    bcmath \
    mysqli \
    pcntl \
    pdo_mysql \
    zip \
    -j$(nproc) gd \
    && docker-php-ext-enable \
    bcmath \
    pcntl \
    redis \ 
    zip \
    && apk del pcre-dev ${PHPIZE_DEPS} \
    && rm -rf /tmp/pear

#install composer
COPY --from=composer:latest /usr/bin/composer /usr/local/bin/composer

WORKDIR /srv/app

#delete when change logs in .env file
COPY --chown=www-data:www-data storage storage

COPY artisan .
COPY public/vendor/js-localization public/vendor/js-localization
COPY bootstrap bootstrap
COPY database database
COPY routes routes
COPY config config
COPY composer.json .
COPY composer.lock .
COPY app app

RUN composer install --optimize-autoloader --no-dev \
    && php artisan js-localization:export


FROM node:alpine as node-modules

WORKDIR /usr/app

COPY --from=laravel-deps /srv/app/public/vendor/js-localization public/vendor/js-localization
COPY .npmrc .
COPY resources resources
COPY package.json .
COPY package-lock.json .
COPY webpack.mix.js .

#isntalling node modules
RUN npm ci \
    && npm run prod


FROM laravel-deps as laravel-app

WORKDIR /srv/app

COPY .env .env
COPY public public
COPY resources resources

COPY --from=node-modules --chown=www-data:www-data /usr/app/public public
```

My problem comes out when I try to do `php artisan migrate` in my PHP container:

```
Call to undefined function App\Actions\Myfunct\myfunct()
```

Also, when I access my app via browse I get a similar error, but in my view:

```
Call to undefined function brand_assets()
```

The crashed line in my view is:

```
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="57x57" href="<?php echo e(brand_assets('favicon/apple-icon-57x57.png')); ?>">
```

It is some lib or something I missing?

**Update**
I think my autoload is not working. I ran the dump-autoload, and despite that I sill get the same error.

Answer (score 0):

I found my error. I didn't COPY the helper dir into my Img. That's why my helpers didn't show up.